# How to use your expo React Native app offline without running in Terminal?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Hello I am new into learning React Native, Lately I'm on building pdf reader, I wonder if there is anyway Running my react native app while I am outside without having have to start the app on the terminal without publishing it?
I use Expo client.

Comment: What do you mean "without having to start the app on the terminal"? Do you mean using expo's website? And what do you mean by "outside"? Do you mean not being connected via cable/wifi for a few minutes - or hours/days?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Sorry if it wasn't clear enough. I mean right now If I wanted to run my app, I'll need to run through expo client by expo start command. I wondered if I could use my app without through any cable or wifi. Just basically Could I run the app through home screen without running any server-clients?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Expo

To the best of my knowledge, expo requires a server running to open your app via "expo go".

If you want to access your app without wifi/cable you could either

1. Use a tunnel URL

> This way your phone can connect back to your PC so long as you both have internet - without having to share a local wifi network. To start a tunnel you can press "d" to open developer tools, and then select "tunnel" from the connections menu.

2. Publish the app to expo

> By publishing the app to expo you can get a permanent URL to your app. You don't need to keep you PC running.

## React

If you don't mind leaving expo, you can do a standard react native build. This will install the app to your device and from there - you don't need internet anymore.
The details change a bit depending on your os, but here is a guide: https://reactnative.dev/docs/running-on-device

Comment: Oh I see my options more clear now. Thanks for your time helping me out!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run or share the app without start development server and also without expo app user interface, then you can find eas.json file in root directory of your project and disable developmentClient. i.e.`"developmentClient": false,` then create development build by running this command in terminal `eas build --profile development --platform ios`.